# How to send a cookie from one activity to another to maintain the session in Android?

Tags: android, cookies

I've seen many answers for the the similar question in here but none on those helped in finding a strategy in achieving sending cookie from one activity to another.

My Problem is, I just want to send a cookie from one Activity to another for maintaining session. But I can't use any of putExtra's including putStringArrayListExtra(), can I?. So How could I achieve this? Is there any strategy. ? Since I'm a beginner please guide me

Edited: I want to send on object of a cookie actually

Comment: why a cookie? Whats the reason for not using Intent? What do you want to achieve? Did you try "savedInstanceState" variable?

Comment: use `SharedPreferrence`

Comment: @nouseforname Of course I'm using Intent for redirecting, But from one activity to another I want to maintain the session so

Comment: @Rustam any references?

Comment: check this link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/

Comment: yes you can maintain session by using singleTon class or using sharedpreferences...

Comment: shared Preferences would be same like "savedInstanceState" var. But mainly, as long as the app is running, it wil keep the activity settings anyway, except you reinit it in "onCreate", "onRestart" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Application class.it is available through whole application.

See [Android Application class](http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/) tutorial for that.
You can generate getter setter for your cookie object and use

```
getApplication().getCookie();
```

and

```
getApplication().setCookie(objCookie);
```

Hope it will help.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class and store the cookie in a static variable. Then you can maintain you session in any Activity by calling [Class].[Varaible] without sending it